# react js writing out data from json

Tags: reactjs

im try to learn reactjs and i have come across a little issue.

i can get hello world wrote out on a page and now i am trying to get data from an api to be wrote out.

i can console.log my data like this console.log(this.state.data);
which returns something like this in the console

{"planets":
[{"id":"1","planetAge":"100","media":[{"name":"mars","url":"/images/1"}]},{"id":"2","planetAge":"200","media":[{"name":"venus","url":"/images/2"}]},{"id":"3","planetAge":"300","media":[{"name":"saturn","url":"/images/3"}]},{"id":"4","planetAge":"400","media":[{"name":"earth","url":"/images/4"}]},{"id":"5","planetAge":"500","media":[{"name":"jupiter","url":"/images/5"}]}]}

how do i get this wrote out on my page i though it was something like this

```
render() {
    if(this.state.data) {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
        <div class="planet">
          <h1>{item.name}</h1>
          <span>{item.planetAge}</span>
          <img src="{item.url}" />
        </div>

        )
    }

    return (<h1>Loading...</h1>);
}
```

but i just keep getting errors

Comment: You might want to consider showing the errors you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Data contain a key `planets`, its an `array` of `object`, you need to use map to print all the values. When you run map on `this.state.data.planets`,  item inside `map` body will be each `object` of the `array` and then you can access the values by `item.planetName` etc.

Use this:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.data) {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <div>
              {this.state.data.planets.map(item => {
                  return(
                      <div class="planet">
                          <h1>{item.media[0].name}</h1>
                          <span>{item.planetAge}</span>
                          <img src={item.media[0].url} />
                      </div>
                  )
              })}                
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (<h1>Loading...</h1>);
}
```

**Update:**

Define the data in constructor as `null` or if you defined the data as []
 then check the length by `if(this.state.data.lenght)`, if you defined data as `{}` then check where it contains the `planets` key or not by `if(this.state.data.planets)`.

Check this:

```js
let data = {"planets": [{"id":"1","planetAge":"100","media":[{"name":"mars","url":"/images/1"}]},{"id":"2","planetAge":"200","media":[{"name":"venus","url":"/images/2"}]},{"id":"3","planetAge":"300","media":[{"name":"saturn","url":"/images/3"}]},{"id":"4","planetAge":"400","media":[{"name":"earth","url":"/images/4"}]},{"id":"5","planetAge":"500","media":[{"name":"jupiter","url":"/images/5"}]}]}

data.planets.map(item => {
   console.log(item. planetAge, item.media[0].name, item.media[0].url)
})
```

Comment: hi thanks for this but i get the following error Uncaught TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function

Comment: you need to use `this.state.data.planets.map`, check the updated answer i did a mistake :)

Comment: hi, im now getting this error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: define `data: null` in `state` variable because you are using the condition to hold the rendering, if you define the data as `[]` then you need to change the `if` condition to `if(this.state.data.length)`, means check the length of the array :)

Comment: @stuartharding check the updated answer, let me know if face any issue :)

Comment: this bit is null  

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
   data: null
  }
 }

Comment: map part is proper, it should work can you show the complete code, are you using map at any other place ?

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getData } from '../api';

export default
class VehicleList extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
   data: null
  }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  getData((data) => {
   this.setState({
    data
   })
  });
 }

Comment: render() {
  if(this.state.data) {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <div>
              {this.state.data.vehicles.map(item => {
                  return(
                      <div class="planet">
                          <h1>{item.media[0].name}</h1>
                          <span>{item.modelYear}</span>
                          <img src="{item.media[0].url}" />
                      </div>
                  )
              })}                
            </div>
        )
    }

  return (<h1>Loading...</h1>);
 }
}

Comment: you are using `vehicles`, but in the data `planets` key is present, so you need to use `this.state.data.planets.map`

Comment: ignore the vehicles bit sorry i was trying something else

Comment: please help i still have the same issue Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @stuartharding code that i suggested is proper, it should work don't know why you are facing that issue, are you map any where else in the application ?

Comment: Hi, no i am not using map anywhere else. :(

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your object has an array of planets, so you need to map over then and then return the values. Also you don't have name and url directly under `item`, you have to access them from `media`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 state = {data : {"planets": [{"id":"1","planetAge":"100","media":[{"name":"mars","url":"/images/1"}]},{"id":"2","planetAge":"200","media":[{"name":"venus","url":"/images/2"}]},{"id":"3","planetAge":"300","media":[{"name":"saturn","url":"/images/3"}]},{"id":"4","planetAge":"400","media":[{"name":"earth","url":"/images/4"}]},{"id":"5","planetAge":"500","media":[{"name":"jupiter","url":"/images/5"}]}]}
 }

render() {
    if(this.state.data) {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.data.planets.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <div class="planet">
                    <h1>{item.media[0].name}</h1>
                    <span>{item.planetAge}</span>
                    <img src={item.media[0].url} />
                  </div>
                )
            })}
          </div>
        
        

        )
    }

    return (<h1>Loading...</h1>);
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Check this working snippet, it will help you out apart from Mayank's answer which is correct as well

Answer (score 0):

A few things:
Your return data is an array, so you need to iterate over the array to display each planet. 
If you simply want to display 1 planet, you can do so by using its index (just for testing purposes or something).

```
<div class="planet">
      <h1>{this.state.data.planets[0].media[0].name}</h1>
      <span>{this.state.data.planets[0].planetAge}</span>
      <img src={this.state.data.planets[0].media[0].url} alt={this.state.data.planets[0].media[0].name} />
</div>
```

Remember, your data live (currently) in `this.state.data`. It would be proper to assign the data to variables instead of using `this.state` everywhere inside the jsx.